# bulk update from array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What's the best way in asp.net mvc to take my array and save each element (and attaching a parentId to each as well) to my sql server db in one step?

thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class.  This allows you to bulk copy data into a table in a single call.

Typically, this is used to load data into a staging table, followed by a further call (usually to a stored procedure) which moves the data from the staging table to production table(s).

You may, however, choose to use it to append data directly to a production table.

The approach you choose will obviously be driven by how your database is engineered and the particular data you are loading.